# Which Google storage Solution option to use if I have to query Json Files using SpringBoot?

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql

Application Architecture : Microservices using SpringBoot with JPA

Data Structure : Json Files

Operations : Aggregate Functions Like SUM, MAX, MIN
Group By and Join Operations
Pagination
Conditional Select

Looking for a Cloud Hosted equivalent of MongoDB that addresses the above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the documentation for the different [cloud storage options that Google Cloud offers](https://cloud.google.com/products/storage/). Regarding your architecture, it seems that [Google Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) (or [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/)) would be a good fit for you, taking into consideration that your data structureis based on JSON files.

Here you have an interesting site that may also help you decide the best solution for you, by comparing different options. Here you have a [comparison between Datastore and MongoDB](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Google+Cloud+Datastore%3BMongoDB).

Comment: I have explored Datastore but it does not support aggregate functions or joins which is a primary requirement.

Comment: Then Cloud SQL could work out for you. It supports JSON native type for both MySQL and Postgres, and you will have all those operations you mention as they are typical relational database operations.